# biblatex in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: biblatex, texniccenter

How do I "install" biblatex in texniccenter?

The editor has either an option to use "BibTex" or not. How do I "hook" biblatex into it instead?

Sorry I am completely lost in what I am doing here.

Comment: [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is a package and BibTeX is an external executable program. That's a fundamental difference. So this issue is not really related to TeXnicCenter (TXC).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution is NOT to use bibtex.

In my case, the problem was that Miketex website was down and download of biblatex package failed.

Comment: I think you are confusing some things here. As pointed out by others, biblatex is a package, whereas BibTeX is a program that biblatex can use as a backend, but biblatex can also use biber as a backend. When it comes to TeXnicCenter, the solution is to use its “bibtex” flag and then define the output profile to fit your needs (i.e. use bibtex or biber as a backend).

Comment: Nope - you don't need to use bibtex - because BibLatex works in Texniccenter without it beign checked. I am talking about Project->properties dialog box.

Comment: Ah, okay, I was not aware of this setting. What does it do, anyway?

Comment: I don't know - that was kind of my question

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw that you are the one who posted the question as well (in fact, it would have been better to post a comment to your question rather than an answer). You can specify the backend to use in Build->Define output profiles (as recluze suggested). There, you can also activate and deactivate BibTeX support, i.e. decide whether BibTeX (the program) should be used at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your program in `Build`->`Define output profiles`. There, define the `path to bibtex executable` and in arguments, pass it the argument: `"%bm"`

Let me know if this solves the problem. It gave me headaches in my early years of using TeXnicCenter :)

Comment: True, but not applicable for the `biblatex` package. OTOH, your answer should help with using `biber` (the recommended backend programm for `biblatex`).

Comment: Oh, you're right. I guess this might help then: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/how-to-use-biblatex-and-xelatex-at-the-same-time