# Cite two papers with same first author and year

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style

I am using [`chicago.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chicago) to reference papers. At one point, I have to reference two papers with the same first author and the same year. I don't want to use the cite option that shows all the authors. Instead I would like something like "Smith et al. (2009a)" and "Smith et al. (2009b)".

Is there a way I can do this (without changing to natbib)?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll} 
                 shortcite     & \shortcite{Smith2012}      
                 citeyear      & \citeyear{Smith2012}  \\        
\end{tabular}    

\begin{tabular}{llll}                
                 shortcite     & \shortcite{Smith2012b}                  
                 citeyear      & \citeyear{Smith2012b}    
\end{tabular}    
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I can't help but to suggest you consider moving to [**`biblatex`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex), which has chicago style ([`biblatex-chicago`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-chicago))

Comment: Thank you @henrique, but I have tried that before, and could not get citeyear to work. I will try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you specifically asked for a bibtex solution for the `chicago` package, I couldn't resist to point you to `biblatex`, since *Chicago Manual of Style* biblatex style files are provided by the [**`biblatex-chicago`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-chicago) package.

To change the number of authors that trigger the "et al." string in biblatex, you have the options `maxnames` and `minnames`. Setting them to `1` takes care of your request (it is worth noting, however, that according to `biblatex-chicago` manual, this is not recommended by the *Chicago Manual of Style*). These options can be passed to `biblatex-chicago` package.

You mentioned in your comments not getting `\citeyear` to work in `biblatex`; this might be because `\citeyear` only prints the year field, without the extra label that is appended to disambiguate it. But this is achievable by the `\citeyear*` command.

**N.B.**: Please notice that **`biblatex-chicago`** (v. 0.9.9.a) requires `biber` for its author-year style, as stated in the [manual (§2)](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-chicago):

> [Biber] is required for users who are either using the author-date style or processing a .bib file in Unicode.

<sup>That means you should replace the `bibtex` pass for a `biber` one. Compile this with `[pdf]latex` → **`biber`** → `[pdf]latex` → `[pdf]latex`</sup>

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,maxnames=1,minnames=1]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith2012,
  author = {A. Smith and B. Schmidt},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
@article{Smith2012b,
  author = {A. Smith and B. Schmidt},
  title = {Another title},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\verb!autocite! is the main citation command: it knows if it is in text or in notes, and switches between \verb!\footcite! and \verb!\parencite! accordingly. \autocite[1]{Smith2012}, \autocite[1]{Smith2012b}

\verb!\footcite! is for citations on footnotes\footcite[1]{Smith2012}, \footcite[1]{Smith2012b}

\verb!\parencite! is for citations in parentheses \parencite[1]{Smith2012}, \parencite[1]{Smith2012b}

\verb!\textcite! is for inline citations, like \textcite[1]{Smith2012}, \textcite[1]{Smith2012b}

\verb!\citeyear! cites only the \verb!year! field, not \verb!year+label!: \citeyear[1]{Smith2012b}. To cite the whole label, you should try the starred variant \verb!\citeyear*!: \citeyear*[1]{Smith2012}, \citeyear*{Smith2012b}

You can also have multiple citations with some of these commands: \autocites{Smith2012}{Smith2012b}

%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
%\bibliography{\jobname}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: biblatex-chicago example]

Comment: Thank you, but I do not get the same output as you with your code. I am getting some errors when executing bibtex: found no \citations commands, found no \bibdata command, found no \bibstyle command. This happens even if I move the bibliography to another file. I had this error before, and that is why I changed to chicago.sty

Comment: Please, ignore the former comment, I've checked `biblatex-chicago` manual again, and it requires `biber`. Simply switch to `biber` in the `bibtex` pass.

Comment: I will try that. I am using Texniccenter, so first I will have to check how to do it. I will get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to mention that. For running biber form TeXnicCenter, check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16532/biblatex-in-texniccenter) (but, instead of bibtex, search for the path to *`biber`* executable)

Comment: It worked! I had to update biber for it to work though....Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're considering switching to `biblatex`! However, I don't think you should have accepted my answer, since it doesn't actually address the real issue you asked for...