# biblatex-chicago will not use extrayear if authors differ

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

Actually [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84982/67042) would solve my question about how to use the `extrayear` parameter in `biblatex-chicago-style` **but** I have another special case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,maxnames=1,minnames=1]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith2012,
  author = {A. Smith and S. Else},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
@article{Smith2012b,
  author = {A. Smith and B. Schmidt},
  title = {Another title},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{Smith2012} said something
\cite{Smith2012b} said something else

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Will give:

```
Smith and Else 2012 said something
Smith and Schmidt 2012 said something else
```

However, I'd like it to be:

```
Smith et al. 2012a said something
Smith et al. 2012b said something else
```

Can anyone think of an easy way?

Comment: `biblatex`'s disambiguation features strike again (the idea is that `biblatex` does not want to insinuate that the two works are by the same same set of authors by abbreviating both to "Smith et al." - note also that "et al." is normally taken to be plural, so often two authors are not et-al'd), add `uniquelist=false` to disable them.

Comment: @moewe Wow! That was quick! Please add this as an answer so I can shower you with upvotes!

Comment: See also [Distinguishing with labels a,b,… instead of another author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175505/35864) and [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disable the `uniquelist` feature, you can read more about it in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
uniquelist=false
```

Normally `biblatex` tries to avoid abbreviating two different lists of authors to the same label to avoid confusion (a reader might otherwise erroneously think that both papers were written by the same set of authors).

Note furthermore that normally the "al." part of "et al." is taken to be plural and so should refer to two or more people. In your example the "et al." would be singular, this situation is often avoided by putting down both authors if there are only two (the label becomes longer, but often only marginally so).

Anyway,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,maxnames=1,minnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith2012,
  author = {A. Smith and S. Else},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
@article{Smith2012b,
  author = {A. Smith and B. Schmidt},
  title = {Another title},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2012} said something
\cite{Smith2012b} said something else

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Smith et al. 2012a said something Smith et al. 2012b said something else

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you very much. You are absolutely right about "et al.". And it seems my question is a dupe...

Comment: @n1000 We can mark it as such, if you like.

Comment: I am sorry for not having found that solution earlier. I don't know what good practice would be?

Comment: @n1000 Don't worry about it, duplicates are much easier to find if you know the solution, I often find. I think this question offers little more than the "standard duplicate" (just the short discussion on "et al." I wanted to include) - so we might as well close it. The question will remain searchable after all.