# Biblatex bibliography no longer shows up

Tags: biblatex

I don't know what is going on, but I've moved computers and my biblatex bibliography no longer gets printed.

I do the usual:

```
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\nocite{*}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXworks and click on the play button with the "pdfLaTex" selected.
But there is no bibliography that gets generated!
All it says is:

```
54 LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 54.
```

which is the line that says `\printbibliography`.

I am using Windows 7. I tried MikTeX, and just tried TeXworks (from TeX Live) – same thing.

I have no idea what's going on, any help?

Comment: i have to ask: did you copy the file references.bib to the new computer???

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder as the file I am compiling "main.tex".

Comment: Did you run latex - bibtex - latex?
(Sorry, really a wild guess...)

Comment: @Rainer: thanks for the guess! I converted this into a comment to the question, as the answer space below is reserved for real answers.

Comment: Edited: I am using "TeXworks" and have "pdfLaTeX" option selected when I press "play" button.

Comment: As Rainer hinted: Compile with "pdflateX", then "BibTeX", then "pdfLaTeX".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I used bibtex and no "biber" to compile my latex file.
I found an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6150/how-to-use-biblatex-and-xelatex-at-the-same-time) on SO:

> From the topmenu: Build/Define Output Profiles/
>
> Path to bibtex executable: "fill in location of biber.exe"
>
> Command line arguments to pass to Bibtex: "%bm" (is same as main
>   file's full path without extension)