# CV Template: Having issues with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the [CV template](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cv/) created by [Rob J Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/) and MWE is given below. In past, every thing was working fine but now `biblatex` is not working properly (see below snap). Even I updated the packages but no success. Any help to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cv}

\name{Rob J Hyndman}
\info{Address: & Department of Econometrics \& Business Statistics, Monash University, VIC 3800, Australia.\\
      Phone: & +61 3 9905 2358\\
      Email: & Rob.Hyndman@monash.edu\\
      WWW: & robjhyndman.com}

\bibliography{CVTest}
\addtocategory{papers}{yaseen2005modeling}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{publications}
\printbib{papers}
\end{publications}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `biblatex` package in your preamble?

Comment: Thanks @RoeyAngel for your comment. I've already tried `\usepackage{biblatex}` but without any success.

Comment: Just a guessing: `biber` is the default backend for newer version of `biblatex`. You compiler profile in TexNicCenter is set up to use `bibtex`. Either try using `backend=bibtex` as option to the `biblatex`-package `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, or update the TeXNicCenter profile to use `biber`.

Comment: This problem can be solved by using the instructions given [here][1], and [here][2].


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6172/4821
  [2]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63048/4821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runs on my machine: linux+texlive+latest biblatex.
Can you confirm that `biblatex` works for you using a minimal document without the `cv` package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cv}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {Doe, J. and Dane, D., and Dewy, R.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {This and That},
  journal = {Journal of Deep Understanding of Things},
}

\end{filecontents}


\name{Rob J Hyndman}
\info{Address: & Department of Econometrics \& Business Statistics, Monash University, VIC 3800, Australia.\\
      Phone: & +61 3 9905 2358\\
      Email: & Rob.Hyndman@monash.edu\\
      WWW: & robjhyndman.com}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\addtocategory{papers}{ref1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{publications}
\printbib{papers}
\end{publications}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've the same issue with you MWE. Could elaborate more about `pdflatex biber pdflatex` sequence? I'm on `Windows 7` and using `TeXnicCenter` editor.

Comment: do you also have biber installed? this is required for compiling documents with `biblatex`

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to install these on Windows.  But to compile a document you need to run once `pdflatex docname` (or `xelatex` etc.) then `biber docname` then again `pdflatex docname`. I guess in `TeXnicCenter` you just press a button to compile it but try to see if you can add a new function that would run `biber` when you press a button.  
This is possible in `kile`.

Comment: Have you seen this thread?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53959/biblatex-biber-in-texniccenter-does-not-produce-bibliography

Comment: If you are using TeXnicCenter on Windows 7 I'm guessing you are also using MikTeX. If you open the MikTeX Package Manager you can search for the package and install it if it is not installed.